# Is it normal to return actor's proxy from service

Tags: azure, actor, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

I have some service which accepts some data and then, as I think, should return an actor initialized with some values.

```
public class MyService : StatefulService, IMyService
{
    public IMyActor DoThings(Data data)
    {
        var actor = ActorProxy.Create<IMyActor>(new ActorId(Guid.NewGuid()));  
        actor.Init(data);
        //some other things
        return actor;
    }
}
```

Another service would do this:

```
var service = ServiceProxy.Create<ICommandBrokerService>(new Uri("fabric:/App"), ServicePartitionKey.Singleton);
var actor = service.DoThings(data);
var state = actor.GetState();
//...
```

So, is it okay to return an actor in such a way, or should I return actor's id and request a proxy on a call sight?

**UPD:**
According to a @LoekD 's answer I did a wrapper to be a little type-safety.

```
[DataContract(Name = "ActorReferenceOf{0}Wrapper")]
public class ActorReferenceWrapper<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public ActorReference ActorReference { get; private set; }
    public ActorReferenceWrapper(ActorReference actorRef)
    {
        ActorReference = actorRef ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    public T Bind()
    {
        return (T)ActorReference.Bind(typeof(T));
    }

    public IActorService GetActorService(IActorProxyFactory serviceProxy=null)
    {
        return ActorReference.GetActorService(serviceProxy);
    }

    public TService GetActorService<TService>(IActorProxyFactory serviceProxyFactory) where TService : IActorService
    {
       return serviceProxyFactory.CreateActorServiceProxy<TService>(ActorReference.ServiceUri,
                ActorReference.ActorId);
    }

    public static implicit operator ActorReference(ActorReferenceWrapper<T> actorRef)
    {
        return actorRef.ActorReference;
    }

    public static explicit operator ActorReferenceWrapper<T>(ActorReference actorReference)
    {
        return new ActorReferenceWrapper<T>(actorReference);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the types used in SF remoting must be `DataContractSerializable`. The contracts you use can only have fields and properties, no methods.

So, instead of returning the proxy, return an [Actor Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.actorreference.get.aspx).

Next, use [Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.actorreference.bind?view=servicefabricactors-2.5.216#Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Actors_ActorReference_Bind_System_Type_) to create a proxy from it.

Comment: So, I'll call `Bind(typeof(IMyActor))` on the returned `Actor Reference` object. But it looks not so type safety, isn't it? I mean, looking on service's interface signature it wouldn't be clear what type of an actor will be returned. Also, I checked on my local cluster and there was no error when return `Actor Proxy` from another service.

Comment: No it's not a descriptive contract. But you can make the ActorReference a property of a larger contract that holds more information about the Actor Type, to make it more user friendly,

Comment: I've updated question with a little type-safety workaround.